# How to get an old ID and insert into a new text field

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a scenario, where I create a new user. Since, I will be creating tons of new users for regression, I am assigning a time-stamp to distinguish each user id. For instance, ABC_2015020615215, ABC_2015020615222, etc.
The code for creating and sending a user with the time-stamp:

```
public static String now = "_" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date());

// user
public static String user_id = PropertyLoader.loadProperty("USER_ID") + now;
```

Next scenario: I need to grab the last user added, and insert into a new text field, on a different page. (remaining on the same driver session).

This code creates a new user:

```
//enter user id in the text field and add a new user
driver.findElement(By.name(PvtConstants.ADD_USER_ID_TEXT_FIELD)).sendKeys(user_id);
```

This is a new text field, where I need to insert the user that was added in the previous step. I am not able to figure that out. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
driver.findElement(By.id(PvtConstants.READ_USER_ADVANCED_FILTER_USER_SEARCH_FIELD));
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table smallInput dataTable" id="dataTableAdvertisers" ">
<thead>
<tr role="row" style="height: 0px;">
<th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" "></th>
<th class="sorting" tabindex="0" "></th>
<th class="sorting" tabindex="0" "></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
    <tr class="odd">
    <td class="">
    <a href="getadvertiserdetailsNew.do?advertiserKey=198909">Advertiser_20150204130817</a></td>
    <td class="">---</td>
    <td class="">---</td>
    <td class="">---</td>
    <td class="">---</td>
    </tr><tr class="even">
    <td class="">
    <a href="getadvertiserdetailsNew.do?advertiserKey=198910">Advertiser_20150204130923</a></td>
    <td class="">---</td>
    <td class="">---</td>
    <td class="">---</td><td class="">---</td>
    </tr><tr class="odd">

   </tbody>
   </table>
```

Comment: What happen when you add an user? Does it create an unorder list or link? or what?

Comment: Yes, it creates a table, where each user is in <tr>. And in the UI, those users are clickable

Comment: Can you provide the `html` of the table then?

Comment: @Saifur html added above. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder why abcd/ab does not contain the timestap you are adding? Should you call toString to conver the date time to string? Using than you can write an `xpath`  or `linkText()` to locate the element easily

Comment: I tested the `now` and that looks good. But I wonder why the `tr` does not contain that now string?

Comment: oh I added these two manually...i was getting their ids...but I can add with date, if you prefer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use a `Xpath` and with passing the `user_id` as parameter. 
Note: this xpath matches the any `a` tag with the text supplied by the `user_id` variable which in your case is the lastly instantiated variable with timestamp.

```
By byXpath = By.xpath("//a[.='" + user_id + "']");

WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(byXpath));
String newUser  = myDynamicElement.getText().trim();

//send newUser this to the search field
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not able to understand the code above, mainly the click part. Where do you want me to click?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I misread your code too. Can you please explain `This is a new text field, where I need to insert the user that was added in the previous step` what you need to insert? Something like `Advertiser_20150204130923`?

Comment: Yes, I need to insert the same user_id that was added in the previous step, which is Advertiser_20150204130923. So, the real scenario is, create a user, and add it. Then go to another screen. That page has a field, where all the user ids are listed. On the page, there is a search field.  Select the search field, insert the same user_id that was created in the previous step. It should filter the search and show only that user_id in the list...

Comment: Then why don't you use `sendKeys(user_id)` to that search field?

Comment: Then it injects the new time stamp...haha, because each time i use user_id, it will create a new id with a new time-stamp

Comment: Wow, Saifur!, I wish I could vote you up millions of times. Man you are just Awesome!. It works, and works very Beautifully!!!!!!! Keep up the good work :)

Comment: Appreciate the nice words. I am glad it helped you.